# Listview with flexbox showing all items in one row

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I have a problem styling with FlexBox.

In my code below, there is a listview with section headers. Each section header has items under it.

The problem is, all items are shown in one row. How can I fix it? I tried adding width 100% for each row but it didn't work.

Thanks in Advance!

```html
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  // Default Loading View
  loading: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    flex: 1,
    //fontFamily: 'Rokkitt',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 5,
    paddingTop: 40,
  },
  // Table
  listView: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    paddingTop: 60,
  },
  // Table Row
  rowContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    padding: 20,
  },
  // Text wrapper within row
  textContainer: {
    flex: 1
  },
  // Row separator
  separator: {
    height: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#E3E0D7'
  },
  // Row Post Title
  title: {
    color: '#3D728E',
    //fontFamily: 'Rokkitt',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  // Row Post Description
  description: {
    color: '#7C705F',
    //fontFamily: 'Josefin Sans',
    fontSize: 14,
    lineHeight: 20,
    marginTop: 8,
    textAlign: 'left',
  },
});


class Courses extends Component {


  render() {
    if (!this.state.loaded) {
      return this.renderLoadingView();
    }

    return (
      <View style={{
        flex: 1
      }}>
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderRow}
        style={styles.listView}
      />
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderRow(data) {
    var rowPress = () => {
      console.log('row pressed');
    };

    var header = (
      <View>
          <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
            <View  style={styles.textContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>{data.nid}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.description} numberOfLines={0}>{data.title}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.separator}></View>
    </View>
    );
///////////

    var content = [];
    for(var x=0; x < Object.keys(data.course).length; x++){
      content.push(
        <TouchableHighlight
        underlayColor='#e3e0d7'
        key={x}
        onPress={rowPress()}
        >
        <Text style={{
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: 'column',
          flexWrap: 'wrap',
        }}>{data.course[x].title}</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      );
    }
    var clist = (
      <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
      {content}
      </View>
    );
////////////
    return (
      <Accordion
        header={header}
        content={clist}  //// <<< Problem! contents are shown in one line, i need each item to wrap whole line>>>
        easing="easeOutCubic"
      />
    );
  }

  renderLoadingView() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.loading}>
        <Text style={styles.loading}>
          Fetching Courses, please wait...
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are a couple of general CSS / Flexbox concepts that may help identify the problem.

---

In standard CSS, the initial value of `flex-direction` is `row`. This means that items will line up horizontally. For vertical alignment, override the default with `flex-direction: column`.

However, in React Native, the default `flex-direction` is `column`.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html#flex-direction

Note that when you switch `flex-direction`, keyword alignment properties such as `align-items` and `justify-content`, switch directions, as well.

---

Another flexbox initial setting (in both CSS and React) is `flex-wrap: nowrap`.
This means items will remain in a single line.

To create a multi-line flex container, override the default with `flex-wrap: wrap`.